# Android setOnKeyListener not firing off

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to execute some code, which is for now a `Toast` when I hit the "enter" key on my in phone keyboard after a user enters something in an `EditText`, but the listener code does not get executed when I press enter.

I've read in plenty of examples that some people use `setOnKeyListener()` and others use `setOnEditListener()`. `setOnEditListener()` caused errors for me and `setOnKeyListener()` just doesn't execute, which is why I went with `setOnKeyListener()` because I'm assuming it's an easier fix.

```
mQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query);
mQuery.setImeActionLabel("Search", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);

mQuery.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, event.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
            //TODO implement action
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "GETTING IT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

EDIT: this is my xml file. I don't do anything with the `imeAction` labels here

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/query"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:inputType="text"/>
```

Comment: You can override the onKeyDown method from the activity class, and detect the keys pressed.

Comment: nothing fires. I have put my xml file in case it's anything I'm not doing correctly in there

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this

```
    EditText mQuery = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query);
    mQuery.setOnKeyListener(this);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH || 
        keyCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
        event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
        event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

        if (!event.isShiftPressed()) {
            //TODO implement action
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "GETTING IT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
```

For a more detailed explanation look at: [Android EditText onKey Event](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/06/android-edittext-enterkey-event-example.html).

Comment: still not firing. Don't know why. Could it be something with my xml file that I'm not setting?